# What is the correct way to do calculations based on state properties in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

I have some Vuex properties that are dependent on each other and I would like to know the best way to do calculations with them.

For instance,

I have a `fontSize` property in my state that has a value of 16.

```
state: {
    fontSize: 16,
}
```

Now I would also like to have a lineHeight that is calculated by multiplying the fontSize by a factor of `1.4`.

So I could say in my getters for example:

```
getters: {
   lineHeight: state => state.fontSize * 1.4
}
```

Is this the correct way of doing things or should I use Mixins / new Vue3 composition API instead of Vuex for these types of calculations?

Comment: `State`: Grocery store. Many people need it. `Mixin`: My House, my family and friends need it when they visit. `In Component`: My Bedroom, only I need this.

Comment: That's a very good way of describing it :). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's correct according to [official doc](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#getters) :

> Sometimes we may need to **compute** derived state based on store state, for example filtering through a list of items and counting them

and you could also use a computed property called `lineHeight` based on `fontSize` state property :

```
computed:{
   lineHeight(){
      this.$store.state.fontSize*1.4
   }

}
```

Comment: Awesome, read the docs and indeed it is there. Thank you :).