# Most efficient way to filter an API response

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm building a stock market overview app in Vue (+Vuex), getting market data from an API, then being updated every x seconds over websocket

Now i want to have a little section that shows "best performing markets"

I'm wondering what would be the most efficient way to handle this calculation.

(all in pseudocode)

## 1

(in vue component)

```
computed: {
  getTopMarkets() {
     filterTopMarkets(this.$store.state.markets)
  }
}
```

## 2

(in vuex getter)

```
getters: {
  topMarkets() {
    return filterTopMarkets(state.markets)
  }
}
```

#3
(other possibilities i am missing?)

is there a difference to the two approaches above (calculate in a computed property vs. calculate in a vuex getter)? is one faster than the other? better than the other? why?

thanks! :)

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402625/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-calculations-based-on-state-properties-in-vuex/63402660#63402660

Comment: that answer basically says "you can do one or the other". but is there a difference in performance?

Comment: Both Vuex getters and computed properties are getters. Which means they're both cached and only re-run when their dynamic dependencies change. The difference is you're changing the place where you are caching them. If you're only using them in one component, there is no difference (but why are you passing them through $store in that case!??). If in more than one component, use vuex getters. But really, the difference is practically non-existent in terms of performance.

Comment: In all fairness, in this case you shouldn't be concerned about code performance. You should be concerned of your (or your team's) performance around maintaining and scaling the resulting code. That's the game changer, that's where the time is spent (and money lost) and that's what you should base your decision upon.

Comment: there's no difference in terms of performance but i see that you should keep that calculations in your store and just use `mapGetters` in computed property which keeps the code more organized

Comment: thanks guys. if there's no performance difference, i'll go with the store getter i guess. if anyone wants to post that as an answer i'll accept it :P

Comment: Whoever voted for closing this question for being opinion based: it's not opinion based. The fact computed and Vuex getters internally use the same mechanism is not common knowledge and not clearly documented, therefore the question is legitimate and, once answered, likely to be useful to future visitors asking the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Vuex `getters` and computed component properties are JavaScript getters.

The long syntax of a computed is:

```
computed: {
  yourComputed: {
    get: function() { return expression }
  }
}
```

equivalent of:

```
computed: {
  yourComputed() { return expression }
}
```

and you can always define setters for computed:

```
computed: {
  yourComputed: {
    get: function() { return expression },
    set: function(value) {
      // dispatch an action or commit a mutation using value
    }
  }
}
```

---

This, combined with Vue's reactivity (or change detection mechanism) means that once they're run once, every time they're requested again Vue will serve the previously computed value - that's why they're called *computed* - (without actually re-running the code) until the moment any of the dynamic bits (references) change. When references change, the getter (whether it's a Vuex getter or a computed property) is rerun and all places where its referenced are notified (and those are re-run/re-rendered, in turn).

The only difference between the two cases is: Vuex getters are cached at store level, computed props are cached at component level.

In terms of both performance and change detection they're basically the same (internally they use the same mechanism).
Now, if you're only using this in one single component, the recommendation is not to use Vuex, as you'll have unnecessary additional boilerplate code around your data.
You're better off using a private store inside your component (either [Vue.observable()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable) or a [Vue instance](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch) - before Vue.observable() was a thing, that was the way to create a basic Store without all the bells and whistles a Vuex store comes with).
*Note:* The mentioned alternatives allow you to expose the component's private store. If you don't need to expose it, don't bother: each component already has a private store: the `data` function (exposed to template). All you need to do is declare the reactive props upfront and from that point on the component will react to applied changes.

As already stated in the comment below your question, the choice here should not be based on code performance (as it's basically the same), but based on development and code management performance.
On how much your project will benefit from the order/structure Vuex comes with, in the long run:

- how complex will your app get in time,
- how many developers are/will be  working on it and how well defined are the project's private conventions (if any)
- how decoupled do you want/need data management and components to be)
- how many iterations of this app are you expecting/foreseeing?

The more complex the project (codebase size, data structure complexity, app logic complexity, number of app iterations, number of developers), the more benefit you'll get from using Vuex, IMHO.

Comment: @Tony, removing it. On this. the mechanics of change detection in Vue are still a bit unclear when it comes to the relation between template tracking and data. I mean, I know how to fix it (replace the array with a new spread version of itself) but I'm not really sure why I need to do this.

Comment: After seeing your statement, I saw this useful [article](https://itnext.io/anyway-should-i-nest-data-or-should-i-not-in-vue-js-8536c86a612f). It's very informative.